# How to pause C# code for ten minutes at the start of each hour

Tags: c#, timer, wait

I'm trying to get my application to pause for nine to ten minutes at the start of each hour.

I've been able to get my application to pause for that amount of time

```
Random waitTime = new Random();
int milliseconds = waitTime.Next(3000, 5000);
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(milliseconds);
```

I shortened the time in my code for testing purposes.

Now I need to tie that into something that checks if the current time is in between (4:00, 4:10) or (5:00, 5:10) or (21:00, 1:00) and resume if it is not.

Comment: What are you actually doing with your app? Could you provide some background context? 99% of the time, `Thread.Sleep` is the wrong way to go about this sort of thing and I'd usually advise against it.

Comment: Do you need the code to pause for ten minutes, or could it be rephrased that whatever it does, you only need to do it in the last 50 minutes of each hour?

Comment: You use a scheduler.

Comment: I would avoid using Thread.Sleep at all costs. Use a scheduler like Quartz.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb Why?

Comment: The environment I'm operating in is very limited, I can't use a scheduler. @TheGeneral

Comment: I'm also relatively new to coding, so I wouldn't know how to implement Quartz
@WilliamXifaras

Comment: @ScottHannen
Yea, that would also work

Comment: Relative new to coding isnt a thing, anyone can work anything out

Comment: @BrootsWaymb
I don't know what else to do, I'm kinda new to coding. I only managed to cobble that together from several different posts here.

Comment: @TheGeneral True, but I thought it might be easier and faster to ask someone. That's usually what I do when I'm out of my element.

Comment: It's part of a larger program, I'm using someone else's work. They did put a spot in for custom code, written in c#. I'm trying to add functions that I want to it.

Comment: @WilliamXifaras It seems like it only works in Java applications. I'm trying to have a c# script that accomplishes this.

Comment: It's not just Java. Search for Quartz.NET. Only executing something during permissible times is pretty much why these schedulers exist.

Comment: @shad Because the whole thread stops. If your application doesn't have multi threading built in, the interface will stop responding as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wish to continue with your current pattern of using `Thread.Sleep(n)`, can use a simple loop.

```
while (DateTime.Now.Minute <=10)
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

In general though it would be better to schedule the task or at least to use async instead of blocking the thread.

Comment: When I try to compile that, I get the error:

'Ststem.DateTime' does not contain a definition for 'Minutes' and no extension method 'Minutes' accepting a first argument of type 'System.DateTime' could be found. (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: Changed "minutes" to "minute"